# how to automatically delete a record from a structure after a specific time in c++

Tags: c++11

i have a structure containing data which are stored in a linked list along with its time of entry into the list. I want the data to get expired after a specific time (say 2 minutes). How to implement this in c++?

Comment: You need to research timers.  If you want to get fancy you can have each object in the list maintain a timer, but that could get computationally expensive, so it would probably be best to use a timer to set off a scan of the list every so often and drop entries that are too old.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any code for us to review, here is the general idea for a method to remove the expired data from your linked list.

```
#include <ctime>

static double const TIME_EXPIRED = 120.0; // seconds

void removeExpired()
{
    while ( ! myList.empty() )
    {
        double secondsElapsed = difftime(time(), myStructInList.entryTime);
        if (secondsElapsed > TIME_EXPIRED)
        {
            // remove element
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, but here the data is expired only when the method is called. I want the data to get expired automatically.

Comment: then each data object in your linked list will have to have it's own timer context with a callback to invoke.  You could have a look at boost asio timers to get an idea.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html  good luck.